# How to overrideMin/Max for Time Axis in Dimple?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am using Dimple to plot data with dates on the Y axis, times of the day (0-23) on the X axis. Now I would like to always have the Y axis range cover a whole month and the X axis cover the whole 24 hours of a day.

Dimple offers overrideMin and overrideMax but for Time Axes I have no idea how to specify the values: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#overrideMin

I made a minimal example at http://jsfiddle.net/mfhrpy6e/

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var data = [
    {'Date': '04-03-2013', 'Time': '13:05:01'},
    {'Date': '10-03-2013', 'Time': '12:45:52'},
    {'Date': '19-03-2013', 'Time': '05:08:21'},
    {'Date': '23-03-2013', 'Time': '21:55:01'},
];

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Time", "%H:%M:%S", "%H");
var y = myChart.addTimeAxis("y", "Date", "%d-%m-%Y", "%d-%m");
var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bubble);
myChart.draw();
```

Comment: For dates it is for example 'y.overrideMin = new Date("2013-03-01");'

Comment: http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_time_axis uses a hack by setting all times to a full date on 2000-01-01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using d3 to create the date objects for the max and min values:

```
x.overrideMin = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse("00:00:00");
x.overrideMax = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse("23:59:59");
```

The hack is only if you want to go from 00:00:00 to 00:00:00 when you have to introduce days, otherwise the system has no way of distinguishing them.

Here's fiddle simplifying your answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/mfhrpy6e/6/

Answer (score 0):

http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_time_axis does it but uses a hacky workaround.

Dimple expects the min/max to be in D3's date format here. There does not seem to be an accompanying time format/object. The workaround in the example is putting all the Times on the same date on 01/01/2000, then specifies the min and max time on that date.

First add the date to each time:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d["Time"] = "2000-01-01 " + d["Time"];
}, this);
```

and then specify the min/max:

```
// 2000-01-01 does not work here, no idea
x.overrideMin = new Date("01/01/2000 00:00:00");
x.overrideMax = new Date("01/01/2000 23:59:59");
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfhrpy6e/5/

This is really not a satisfying but pretty ugly solution so I won't accept it as an answer to my own question.